# Как спарсить json file в java если он в Unicode

Tags: java, json, unicode, парсер

Как парсить файл json в java если файл json полностью в юникоде, как тут выбрать теги с которых нужно распарсить информацию?

```
{
 "0":"",
 "1240":"\u0404\u0432\u0434\u043e\u043a\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0432\u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0456\u0439\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0456\u0439\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447",
 "1241":"\u0404\u0432\u0434"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Lang](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6) StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava() декодирует.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

@Test
public void testUnescapeJava() {
    String sJava="\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F";
    System.out.println("StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):\n" + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava));
}

 output:
 StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):
 Hello
```

Или такой способ:

```
String myString = "\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World";

String str = myString.split(" ")[0];
str = str.replace("\\","");
String[] arr = str.split("u");
String text = "";
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
    text += (char)hexVal;
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы распарсить *json*, могу посоветовать библиотеку **[JSON in Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)**.

Разбор строки с её помощью будет выглядеть так:

```
String str = "{"value\":\"\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F\"}";

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(str);
System.out.println(object.getString("value"));
```

Вывод:

> Hello